# GETTING RESPONSE FROM WEBSERVICE

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am new for android as well as new for webservices..Kindly help me out

```
anyType{Users=anyType{FirstName=gkdgkfdgzff; LastName=hfhff; PhnNumber=hdd; CreditCard=gdjd; Email=dhd; Country=gdhd; }; }
```

I am getting this response from the webservice, how can I extract values from it and can store in variables??
My webservices are written in the asp.net c#
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your response doesn't look like a valid `JSON` string. Did you alter yourself?

Comment: @Faiza: Did u check on my answer?

Comment: nops @waqas.. I havenot alter it...

Comment: @yes Daniel... But I dont know about the format....

Comment: @Faiza: If the response is not json and it is actually what you have in there, then you'll have to parse it manually when you get the response string from your httpentity wich I don't advice u to do at all.

Comment: I have'nt time @Daniel to use Restfull services. Can u guide me to good tutorial of parse such type of response...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the purposes of WebServices are for allowing the possibility of consuming the exposed data from any platform, that's why the response when you consume it, it comes in formats that every platform has libraries to process(like json), so the fact that is written in asp.net c# is not that important. In Android case parsing responses in Json format is pretty easy by using org.json library, Assuming your response is in json format, wish in your case is not correctly formatted, then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620825/decode-complex-json-string-to-various-objects/16621110#16621110) is a link where I expose a way for parsing a response.

Edit: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116978/how-to-create-rest-api-and-how-to-consume-the-rest-api-with-android-apps/16117033#16117033) is a link for a RestClient I developed myself wich you can use to consume any exposed data via classic http methods(GET and POST). Hope this helps.

Comment: But @Danile, I am getting this reponse from the server side... :(

Comment: jason b nai hy to ya kasy hoga parse @Daniel

Comment: @Faiza: Check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using [`ksoap2`](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) as the webservice consumer and in that case, there is nothing wrong with the response that you have received as `ksoap2` formats the output that way. Follow the code sample in [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data) to extract the values from the response.