# Android webservices what to study

Tags: android, web-services

I would like to Apologize if i am posting in the wrong section.

I am learning android app development. When it came using webservices , xml parsing its a bit confusing as

> i have no knowledge  on working with any type of online data.

I would like some suggestions on what i could study to understand the concept better.

To explain this situation better

I am a c++ programmer who wroks on local applications.
Now with this study i am trying to obtain some data off a website, to display on the mobile in
a proper formatted manner.

really would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) might help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably,if you want to make things properly, the most difficult regarding to this task is building your own [Rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)Client to consume the WebServices, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116978/how-to-create-rest-api-and-how-to-consume-the-rest-api-with-android-apps/16117033#16117033) I provide you one with simple HttpMethods: GET, POST.